# Shiny app only renders first two tables from list of four

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm putting together my first Shiny app and need some help. I'm trying to get the user to be able to choose different views on the same dataset via drop-down list selection.

In a separate R script, I have created my summary tables, I have sourced the script, and run it at the very beginning of my app.

These are the summary tables I would like to use in the app:

SummarybyAgency
[image: SummarybyAgency]

SummarybyCallContext
[image: SummarybyCallContext]

SummarybyLicense
[image: SummarybyLicense]

SummarybyLocation
[image: SummarybyLocation]

I have also created a vector that contains the choices from the dropdown:

```
Views <- c("Agency", "Context", "License", "Location")
```

This is the code in the UI portion of the app:

```
  box(
                    title = "Minute Consumption and Charges", 
                    selectInput("View", "Select view", choices = Views)),
                    dataTableOutput("TableView")
      )
```

And this is on the server side:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  reactive_View <- reactive({
    if(input$View == "Agency") {return (SummarybyAgency)} else {
      if (input$View == "Context") {return(SummarybyCallContext)} else {
        if (input$view == "License") {return(SummarybyLicense)} else {
          if (input$View == "Location") {return(SummarybyLocation)}
        }
      }
    }
    
  })  
 
  
  output$TableView <- renderDataTable(reactive_View(), options = list(pageLength = 5))   

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

However, when I run the app I can select only the first two tables, the other two fail.

Example:

[image: Agency view]

[[image: Context view6]

[image: License view]

[image: Location view]

This is the error in the console:

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  114: <reactive:reactive_View> [app.R#116]
   98: reactive_View
   97: renderDataTable
   96: func
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$TableView
    1: runApp
```

However, if I swap the order of the tables in the nested if statement, I will always see the first two tables (if I put "License" and "Location: in the first two ifs I'll be able to render them, but not Agency and Context.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: And what is stored there in `input$View` when debugging with breakline at `if`s and 3rd or 4th option selected?

Comment: you have `view` instead of `View` in the third `if` statement

Comment: @langtang, that was really it... didn't see the small caps in the third if. Now it works! Thank you!

Comment: @Allenvolm - you might consider the approach below to avoid the nested if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this helps you?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
Views <- c("Agency", "Context", "License", "Location")
ds <- list(
  Agency = data.frame("agency" = c(1,2,3), "b" = c(4,5,6)),
  Context = data.frame("context" = c(4,5,6), "b" = c(4,5,6)),
  License = data.frame("license" = c(7,8,9), "b" = c(4,5,6)),
  Location = data.frame("location" = c(10,11,12), "b" = c(4,5,6))
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  box(
    title = "Minute Consumption and Charges", 
    selectInput("View", "Select view", choices = Views)),
  dataTableOutput("TableView")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$TableView = renderDataTable(
    ds[[input$View]]
  )
}
```